# Android Parse Push Notifications need to change the Parse app

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

I have just implemented Parse Push notifications in my apps and everything is working just fine. However, before release I need to migrate the apps to different Parse apps for various reasons. But when I change the keys to the new Parse apps my devices don't receive the pushes from the new Parse app until I uninstall and re-install the app. This is a problem for our existing users in the field, who in general will be installing updates without uninstalling first.

Is there any way to delete the cached registration associated with the old Parse app before initializing with the new? I assume that would take care of the problem.

Christine

Comment: So even if they get the update to the Android app, it still doesn't get pushes from the new parse app?

Comment: As I said in my answer, that is true only if the previously received version was registered for pushes from the old parse app

Comment: I'm facing this same issue, what were your solution?

Answer (score 0):

My mistake. Since the apps in the field are not currently registered for Parse Push Notifications switching to a new Parse app is not a problem for us. It is only if an app is already registered for Push Notifications that changing to a new Parse app requires uninstallation and re-installation before it will receive notifications from the new Parse app.

Comment: You should edit your question, not add an answer for clarification.